# How can i improve this Javascript code that arrange the array in ordered list first and put them in an array of array with same value?

Tags: javascript

Can this code be Improved? It arrange our array into sorted list(sortedArray) first and, the finalArray takes the final result;Example finalArray = [[1,1,1,1][2,2,2]...]

```js
let array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]
let sortedArray = []
let finalArray = []

sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return sortedArray.push(a - b);
});

finalArray = sortedArray.reduce((item, index) => {
  if (typeof item.last === 'undefined' || item.last !== index) {
    item.last = index;
    item.sortedArray.push([]);
  }
  item.sortedArray[item.sortedArray.length - 1].push(index);
  return item;

}, {
  sortedArray: []
}).sortedArray;
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  Codereviews has its own site

Comment: Can you show us what is the expected output please.

Comment: 0: (4) [1, 1, 1, 1]
1: (3) [2, 2, 2]
2: [4]
3: [5]
4: [10]
5: (2) [20, 20]
6: [391]
7: [392]
8: [591]

Comment: @mplungjan second processing will take the sortedArray and group the same value into an array inside an array. Final result should look like this - [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591]. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version than yours and more readable than Nina's

```js
let array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]

const finalArray = array.slice(0) // copy the array
  .reduce((acc,cur) => {
    const idx = acc.findIndex(item => item[0] === cur);
    if (idx !=-1) acc[idx].push(cur); // just push
    else acc.push([cur]); // push as array
    return acc
  },[])
  .sort(([a],[b]) => a-b); // sort on the first entry

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group first and then sort by the first item of each array.

If you have only positive 32 bit intger values, you could omit sorting, because the object is sorted like an array.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20],
    result = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, v) => {
            (r[v] ??= []).push(v);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice. Thanks for the answer.